# All eigenvalues are positive , still np.linalg.cholesky is giving error that matrix is not positive definite

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

My matrix is positive definite still while doing Cholesky decomposition , numpy is giving error as below [image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the small positive eigenvalue 1.33e-10 is getting treated as zero, resulting in the matrix being treated as positive semi-definite, not positive definite. Perhaps you should explore setting tolerances in Numpy's Cholesky routine. Head over to [scicomp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) where people might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The condition number of a matrix -- the ratio of the largest to the smallest eigenvalue -- for many procedures gives an error amplification factor. In your case it is around 3e19, a lot larger than the (relative) precision of doubles. So it's not surprising that cholesky fails